# Can Haskell's type system enforce correct ordering of data pipeline stages?

Tags: haskell, pipeline, type-systems, type-level-computation

I create a lot of data processing pipelines using mass spectrometry data, where data from the instrument gets cleaned up, transformed, scaled, inspected, and finally analyzed. I tend to use a recursive type definition for this -- here's a heavily simplified example:

```hs
data Dataset = Initial { x::(Vector Double), y::(Vector Double) name::String}
             | Cleaned { x::(Vector Double), y::(Vector Double) name::String}
             | Transformed { x::(Vector Double), y::(Vector Double) name::String}
```

Then a typical pipeline will just be a chain of functions that starts with a `Dataset` creator, and then continue with functions that consume something of type `Dataset`, and produce something of type `Dataset`:

```hs
createDataset :: Vector Double -> Vector Double -> String -> Dataset
createDataset x y name = Initial x y name

removeOutliers :: Dataset -> Dataset
removeOutliers (Initial x y n) = let
                         (new_x, new_y) = outlierRemovalFunction x y
                         in Cleaned new_x new_y (n ++"_outliersRemoved")
               (Cleaned x y n) = error "Already been cleaned"
               (Scaled x y n) = error "Scaled data should have already been cleaned"
               (Transformed x y n) = error "Transformed data should have already been cleaned"

logTransform :: Dataset -> Dataset
logTransform (Initial x y n) = error "Need to clean first"
             (Cleaned x y n) = let
                         (new_x, new_y) = logTransformFunction x y
                         in Transformed new_x new_y (n ++ "_logTransformed)
```

So this makes sure that the processing steps in the pipeline happen in the correct order, and you can create whole pipelines using composition

```hs
(logTransform . removeOutliers . createDataset) init_y init_y "ourData"
```

But this approach seems extremely limited for a couple of reasons. The first reason is that incorrectness is detected via pattern matching on constructors, so additions and changes to the pipeline will require changes everywhere in the pattern matching. Imagining a more complicated example with several cleaning and several transform steps -- basically every possible combination will need its own unique constructor, and all the pattern matching will have to be non-exhaustive, or repeated absolutely everywhere.

The second reason this seems limited is that an incorrectly constructed pipeline is only detected by failures at runtime. I've sequenced all the processing steps, so at every point in the pipeline I know exactly what has happened to the data. The type system should be able to keep me from putting the steps together incorrectly in the first place, and using a function expecting cleaned data on a non-cleaned input should be detectable at compile time.

I have thought about having separate *types* for each of the stages in the pipeline, and then having the "dataset" interface implemented as a type class, something like:

```hs
class Dataset a where
    x :: a -> Vector Double
    y :: a -> Vector Double
    name :: a -> String

data Initial = Initial x y name
instance Dataset Initial where ...

data Cleaned a = Cleaned a
instance Dataset Cleaned where ...

data Transformed a = Transformed a
instance Dataset Transformed where ...
```

then you can do things (I think...) like:

```hs
removeOutliers :: (Dataset a) => a -> Cleaned a
removeOutliers = ...

logTransform :: (Dataset a) => Cleaned a -> Transformed Cleaned a
logTransform = ...
```

I *believe* that this approach fixes issue number 1 above: We can now detect pipeline incorrectness at compile time, and we no longer are stuck with having to have all those different constructors to describe the processing steps.

However, it seems that I've just moved the problem "one level up". I'm now dealing with type variables and all these nested types. Instead of a needing a `Dataset` constructor for every possible combination of pipeline steps, I now need to create a `Dataset` instance for every combination of types!

What I really want is a way for a type in the processing pipeline to be both very specific or very general in their constraints. I'd like to use types/constraints that detail the order in which specific processing steps were applied, but I'd also like for a type/constraint to be able to convey something more general -- i.e. "In addition to other unimportant steps, *outlier removal has been done*". So basically the type of things that have had outliers removed.

Conveying ordering information would be an ultra-bonus -- "In addition to other unimportant steps outlier removal happened and *at some point later on* a log transformation happened". The type of things that have had outliers removed before they were log transformed (and not necessarily *immediately* before).

Is this sort of thing possible using Haskell's type system?

Comment: A useful term to look into is “type-aligned sequence”. Check out the [`type-aligned`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-aligned) package for one implementation. You can also make `Dataset` a GADT indexed with a `DataKinds` type parameter for its “phase”, e.g. `data Phase = PInitial | PCleaned | PTransformed; data Dataset (p :: Phase) where { Initial :: { x, y :: Vector Double, name :: String } -> Dataset 'PInitial; Cleaned :: … Dataset 'PCleaned; … }` and then your functions can have types like `Dataset 'PInitial -> Dataset 'PCleaned` or use `Dataset p` to be polymorphic over the phase.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JonPurdy! Type-aligned sequence is a brand new term to me, and I'm really glad to know about it. Looks super useful! Also thanks for the GADT example! I've been reading about this, and this really helped me make sense of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the modern Haskell type system can handle this.  However, compared to usual, term-level programming, type-level programming in Haskell is still hard.  The syntax and techniques are complicated, and documentation is somewhat lacking.  It also tends to be the case that relatively small changes to requirements can lead to big changes in the implementation (i.e., adding a new "feature" to your implementation can cascade into a major reorganization of all the types), which can make it difficult to come up with a solution if you're still a little uncertain about what your requirements actually are.

@JonPurdy's comment and @AtnNn's answer give a couple of ideas of what's possible.  Here's a solution that tries to address your specific requirements.  However, it's likely to prove difficult to use (or at least difficult to adapt to your requirements)  unless you're willing to sit down and teach yourself a fair bit of type-level programming.

Anyway, suppose you're interested in tagging a fixed data structure (i.e., always the same fields with the same types) with a type-level list of the processes that have been performed on it, with a means to check the process list against an ordered sublist of required processes.

We'll need some extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
```

The process tags themselves are defined as constructors in a sum type, with the `DataKinds` extension lifting the tags from the term level to the type level:

```
data Process = Cleaned | Transformed | Scaled | Inspected | Analyzed
```

The data structure is then tagged with a list of applied processes, its "pipeline":

```
data Dataset (pipeline :: [Process])
  = Dataset { x :: [Double]
            , y :: [Double]
            , name :: String }
```

**NOTE:** It will be most convenient for the pipeline to be in reverse order, with the most recently applied `Process` first.

To allow us to require that a `pipeline` has a particular ordered subsequence of processes, we need a type-level function (i.e., a type family) that checks for subsequences.  Here's one version:

```
type family a || b where
  True  || b = True
  False || b = b

type family Subseq xs ys where
  Subseq '[]      ys  = True
  Subseq nonempty '[] = False
  Subseq (x:xs) (x:ys) = Subseq xs ys || Subseq (x:xs) ys
  Subseq xs     (y:ys) = Subseq xs ys
```

We can test this type-level function in GHCi:

```
λ> :kind! Subseq '[Inspected, Transformed] '[Analyzed, Inspected, Transformed, Cleaned]
Subseq '[Inspected, Transformed] '[Analyzed, Inspected, Transformed, Cleaned] :: Bool
= 'True
λ> :kind! Subseq '[Inspected, Transformed] '[Analyzed, Transformed, Cleaned]
Subseq '[Inspected, Transformed] '[Analyzed, Transformed, Cleaned] :: Bool
= 'False
λ> :kind! Subseq '[Inspected, Transformed] '[Transformed, Inspected]
Subseq '[Inspected, Transformed] '[Transformed, Inspected] :: Bool
= 'False
```

If you want to write a function that requires a dataset to have been transformed and then cleaned of outliers (in that order), possibly intermixed with other, unimportant steps with the function itself applying a scaling step, then the signature will look like this:

```
-- remember: pipeline type is in reverse order
foo1 :: (Subseq [Cleaned, Transformed] pipeline ~ True)
     => Dataset pipeline -> Dataset (Scaled : pipeline)
foo1 = undefined
```

If you want to prevent double-scaling, you can introduce another type-level function:

```
type family Member x xs where
  Member x '[] = 'False
  Member x (x:xs) = 'True
  Member x (y:xs) = Member x xs
```

and add another constraint:

```
foo2 :: ( Subseq [Cleaned, Transformed] pipeline ~ True
        , Member Scaled pipeline ~ False)
     => Dataset pipeline -> Dataset (Scaled : pipeline)
foo2 = undefined
```

Then:

```
> foo2 (Dataset [] [] "x" :: Dataset '[Transformed])
... Couldn't match type ‘'False’ with ‘'True’ ...
> foo2 (Dataset [] [] "x" :: Dataset '[Cleaned, Scaled, Transformed])
... Couldn't match type ‘'False’ with ‘'True’ ...
> foo2 (Dataset [] [] "x" :: Dataset '[Cleaned, Transformed])
-- typechecks okay
foo2 (Dataset [] [] "x" :: Dataset '[Cleaned, Transformed])
  :: Dataset '[ 'Scaled, 'Cleaned, 'Transformed]
```

You can make it all a little friendlier, both in terms of constraint syntax and error messages, with some additional type aliases and type families:

```
import Data.Kind
import GHC.TypeLits

type Require procs pipeline = Require1 (Subseq procs pipeline) procs pipeline
type family Require1 b procs pipeline :: Constraint where
  Require1 True procs pipeline = ()
  Require1 False procs pipeline
    = TypeError (Text "The pipeline " :<>: ShowType pipeline :<>:
                 Text " lacks required processing " :<>: ShowType procs)
type Forbid proc pipeline = Forbid1 (Member proc pipeline) proc pipeline
type family Forbid1 b proc pipeline :: Constraint where
  Forbid1 False proc pipeline = ()
  Forbid1 True proc pipeline
    = TypeError (Text "The pipeline " :<>: ShowType pipeline :<>:
                 Text " must not include " :<>: ShowType proc)

foo3 :: (Require [Cleaned, Transformed] pipeline, Forbid Scaled pipeline)
     => Dataset pipeline -> Dataset (Scaled : pipeline)
foo3 = undefined
```

which gives:

```
> foo3 (Dataset [] [] "x" :: Dataset '[Transformed])
...The pipeline '[ 'Transformed] lacks required processing '[ 'Cleaned, 'Transformed]...
> foo3 (Dataset [] [] "x" :: Dataset '[Cleaned, Scaled, Transformed])
...The pipeline '[ 'Cleaned, 'Scaled, 'Transformed] must not include 'Scaled...
> foo3 (Dataset [] [] "x" :: Dataset '[Cleaned, Transformed])
-- typechecks okay
foo3 (Dataset [] [] "x" :: Dataset '[Cleaned, Transformed])
  :: Dataset '[ 'Scaled, 'Cleaned, 'Transformed]
```

A full code sample:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Kind
import GHC.TypeLits

data Process = Cleaned | Transformed | Scaled | Inspected | Analyzed

data Dataset (pipeline :: [Process])
  = Dataset { x :: [Double]
            , y :: [Double]
            , name :: String }

type family a || b where
  True  || b = True
  False || b = b

type family Subseq xs ys where
  Subseq '[]      ys  = True
  Subseq nonempty '[] = False
  Subseq (x:xs) (x:ys) = Subseq xs ys || Subseq (x:xs) ys
  Subseq xs     (y:ys) = Subseq xs ys

type family Member x xs where
  Member x '[] = False
  Member x (x:xs) = True
  Member x (y:xs) = Member x xs

type Require procs pipeline = Require1 (Subseq procs pipeline) procs pipeline
type family Require1 b procs pipeline :: Constraint where
  Require1 True procs pipeline = ()
  Require1 False procs pipeline
    = TypeError (Text "The pipeline " :<>: ShowType pipeline :<>:
                 Text " lacks required processing " :<>: ShowType procs)
type Forbid proc pipeline = Forbid1 (Member proc pipeline) proc pipeline
type family Forbid1 b proc pipeline :: Constraint where
  Forbid1 False proc pipeline = ()
  Forbid1 True proc pipeline
    = TypeError (Text "The pipeline " :<>: ShowType pipeline :<>:
                 Text " must not include " :<>: ShowType proc)


foo1 :: (Subseq [Cleaned, Transformed] pipeline ~ True)
     => Dataset pipeline -> Dataset (Scaled : pipeline)
foo1 = undefined

foo2 :: ( Subseq [Cleaned, Transformed] pipeline ~ True
        , Member Scaled pipeline ~ False)
     => Dataset pipeline -> Dataset (Scaled : pipeline)
foo2 = undefined

foo3 :: (Require [Cleaned, Transformed] pipeline, Forbid Scaled pipeline)
     => Dataset pipeline -> Dataset (Scaled : pipeline)
foo3 = undefined
```

Comment: This is quite possibly the coolest thing I have ever seen. Thanks so much for taking the time to push this all the way through to type programming -- what an incredible answer! Many years ago I got in a spot of trouble with the authorities for doing inappropriate (and sometimes downright bizarre) things with C++ templates, and in my heart of hearts I've wanted to be back here ever since. The specificity of this, with the hints from the other answers/comments, has made everything I've been trying to learn in the past few weeks click into place. Thank you thank you!!

Comment: If you like this kind of stuff (I do to), you might be interested in Maguire's book [Thinking with Types](https://thinkingwithtypes.com/).  I haven't read the whole thing (just skimmed the sample chapters), but it looks like a good treatment,

Comment: That book looks like a great resource. Thanks for the suggestion! You're right that the documentation in this area is a bit lacking... I tried to learn mostly by looking up individual GHC extensions, but then synthesizing that knowledge was tricky. This book looks like it covers everything really nicely.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a phantom type to store information about your dataset in its type, for example:

```
data Initial
data Cleaned
data Scaled

data Dataset a = Dataset { x :: Vector Double, y :: Vector Double, name :: String }

createDataset :: Vector Double -> Vector Double -> String -> Dataset Initial
createDataset x y name = Dataset x y name

removeOutliers :: Dataset Initial -> Dataset Cleaned
removeOutliers (Dataset x y n) =
    let (x', y') = clean x y
    in Dataset x' y' (n ++ "_clean")
```

With a few GHC extensions you can restrict the phantom type to a given state type and avoid declaring empty data types explicitly. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}

data State = Initial | Cleaned | Scaled

data Dataset (a :: State) = Dataset { x :: Vector Double, y :: Vector Double, name :: String }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've accepted @K.A.Buhr 's answer below as it was pretty much exactly what I was trying to do, but this was also really useful to read. I've encountered phantom types, but didn't really get that you could do *this* with them in such a straightforward way. Cool!